# Issue with Knockout not binding to model

Tags: javascript, c#, json, knockout.js

I have an issue with Knockout binding to a model here is my code. The code fires and returns a JSON object but the table is empty. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

HTML

```
  <table  style="border: double">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>jobId</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <!--Iterate through an observableArray using foreach-->
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: Jobs">
    <tr style="border: solid" data-bind="click: $root.getselectedjob" id="updtr">
    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.jobId "></span></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Javascript

```
var JobViewModel = function () {
    //Make the self as 'this' reference
    var self = this;
    //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
    self.jobId = ko.observable("");
    self.name = ko.observable("");
    self.description = ko.observable("");

    //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
    var jobData = {
        jobId: self.jobId,
        name: self.name,
        description: self.description
    };

    //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
    self.Jobs = ko.observableArray([]);

    GetJobs(); //Call the Function which gets all records using ajax call

    //Function to Read All Employees
    function GetJobs() {
        //Ajax Call Get All Job Records
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Client/GetJobs",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                self.Jobs(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
            }
        });
        //Ends Here
    }

    //Function to Display record to be updated. This will be

    //executed when record is selected from the table
    self.getselectedjob = function (job) {
        self.jobId(job.jobId),
        self.name(job.name),
        self.description(job.description)
        //,
        //self.DeptName(employee.DeptName),
        //self.Designation(employee.Designation)
    };


};
ko.applyBindings(new JobViewModel());
```

C# Method to get jobs

```
    public ActionResult GetJobs(string AccountIDstr)
    {
        //parse this as parameter
        int AccountID = Convert.ToInt32(AccountIDstr);
        AccountID = 1;

        var jobs = (from c in db.jobs
                          select c).OrderByDescending(m => m.jobId).ToList();

        //"Business logic" method that filter jobs by the account id
        var jobsFilter = (from e in jobs
                                 where (AccountID == null || e.accountId == AccountID)
                                 select e).ToList();


        var jobsresult = from jobrows in jobsFilter
                      select new
                      {
                          jobId = jobrows.jobId.ToString(),
                          name = jobrows.name,
                          description = jobrows.description
                      };

        return Json(new
        {
            Jobs = jobsresult
        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JSON Object

```
{"Jobs":[{"jobId":"5","name":"Job 5 ","description":"Job 5 description"},{"jobId":"1","name":"Job 1 ","description":"Job 1 description"}]}
```

Comment: Tried amending the Javascript GetJobs() as below but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Jobs` is an observableArray, but the data is wrapped in an object. When you set the value in `GetJobs`, you should be doing

```
self.Jobs(data.Jobs);
```

Here's a runnable snippet that works. You should be able to run this using your ajax function to populate data. If it doesn't work, examine what you're getting back.

```js
var JobViewModel = function() {
  //Make the self as 'this' reference
  var self = this;
  //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
  self.jobId = ko.observable("");
  self.name = ko.observable("");
  self.description = ko.observable("");

  //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
  var jobData = {
    jobId: self.jobId,
    name: self.name,
    description: self.description
  };

  //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
  self.Jobs = ko.observableArray([]);

  GetJobs(); //Call the Function which gets all records using ajax call

  //Function to Read All Employees
  function GetJobs() {
    //Ajax Call Get All Job Records
    var data = {
      "Jobs": [{
        "jobId": "5",
        "name": "Job 5 ",
        "description": "Job 5 description"
      }, {
        "jobId": "1",
        "name": "Job 1 ",
        "description": "Job 1 description"
      }]
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.Jobs(data.Jobs);
    }, 500);

  }

  //Function to Display record to be updated. This will be

  //executed when record is selected from the table
  self.getselectedjob = function(job) {
    self.jobId(job.jobId),
      self.name(job.name),
      self.description(job.description)
      //,
      //self.DeptName(employee.DeptName),
      //self.Designation(employee.Designation)
  };


};
ko.applyBindings(new JobViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table style="border: double">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>jobId</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--Iterate through an observableArray using foreach-->
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Jobs">
    <tr style="border: solid" data-bind="click: $root.getselectedjob" id="updtr">
      <td><span data-bind="text: $data.jobId "></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: not sure I understand where to set the value. Please explain

Comment: I have amended the code in Javascript as above but still no luck

Comment: Roy your sample works but I am unable to resolve my issue. My solution whilst it returns exactly the same Json object the table is not rendering the result.

Comment: I have replaced the javascript entirely with your one but it still doesn't render the object.

Comment: Are you using the CDN libraries for jQuery and Knockout? Or local ones?

Comment: The code returns exactly what you return in your snippet. I am getting back exactly the same as your 'var data' object so not sure why it is not working.

Comment: I am using local libraries

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I've updated the snippet to use the versions you list, but it still works. Best advice I have is to copy my code (including `<script>` tags that use the CDNs) to your local box and ensure that it runs, then change GetJobs to make the Ajax call and see if it still runs. And of course, check your console for any errors.

Comment: The problem on my box is that your example doesn't work. Which I find puzzling

Comment: Roy the issue is that I have put your code in my solution and it doesn't work. I really don't know why because it is such a simple task that should just work. No errors in the console either.

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: If you can't get the code above to run on your box, I think the problem goes beyond ordinary Knockout.

Comment: something going on in the view preventing the rendering of the table, I have no idea what but I have started the view from scratch and every knock-out function works.